# IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005

Tags: powerbi

I am getting this error message when trying to specify SQL query. Any idea's on how to resolve this error?  Thank you

```
SELECT DimProduct.ProductKey, 
DimProduct.ProductAlternateKey, 
DimProduct.WeightUnitMeasureCode, 
DimProduct.SizeUnitMeasureCode, 
DimProduct.EnglishProductName, 
DimProduct.ListPrice, 
DimProduct.Size, 
DimProduct.SizeRange, 
DimProduct.Weight, 
DimProduct.Color, 
DimProductCategory.EnglishProductCategoryName, 
DimProductSubcategory.EnglishProductSubcategoryName
FROM (DimProduct INNER JOIN DimProductSubcategory 
ON DimProduct.ProductSubcategoryKey = DimProductSubcategory.ProductSubcategoryKey) 
INNER JOIN DimProductCategory 
ON DimProductSubcategory.ProductCategoryKey = DimProductCategory.ProductCategoryKey;
```

Comment: Check that all columns that are used in the statement exists in your data set.

Comment: Either some of the objects referenced by this query doesn't exists, or you have no permissions.